# Varnish caches a response that has been generated by vcl_backend_error

Tags: varnish

We're running a setup with Varnish caching backend requests to multiple backend instances. This is handled using the Director VMOD. When a new deploy of new code is done on the backend servers, they will be offline for a few seconds, maybe a minute, but it is a staggered deploy, so first the code will be deployed to one instance and when that is back online, to the next, etc.

When an instance is deploying it will shutdown its webserver to make sure no requests are handled mid-deploy. To handle this, the Varnish VCL has a restart loop built in:

```
sub vcl_deliver {
# Restart specifically to catch timeouts on deploy
if (resp.status >= 500) {
    # Restart goes to vcl_req and the director should choose another backend from the pool
    return(restart);
}
```

Forcing a restart will get result in the Director VMOD grabbing the next instance which is not deploying (as only one deploys at the same time) and getting a valid answer. This works fine.

However, when a backend fetch results in a `FetchError     HTC status -1` (unexpected end of input, caused by the webserver shutting down midrequest) the vcl_backend_error subroutine is called. When this happens, a restart will be triggered as expected but Varnish will not go to vcl_backend_fetch but apparantly cached the generated response in VCL_backend_error and returns that instead. Below relevant parts of the original response and the restarted response:

```
    VCL_call       RECV
-   VCL_return     hash
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 101974384 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1545038546.336891 8.103600 8.103600
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     503
-   RespReason     Backend fetch failed
-   RespHeader     Date: Mon, 17 Dec 2018 09:22:26 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 101974383
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.0)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   VCL_return     restart
-   Timestamp      Process: 1545038546.336900 8.103608 0.000008
-   Timestamp      Restart: 1545038546.336902 8.103611 0.000003
-   Link           req 101974385 restart
-   End

    VCL_call       RECV
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   Hit            101974384
-   VCL_call       HIT
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     503
-   RespReason     Backend fetch failed
-   RespHeader     Date: Mon, 17 Dec 2018 09:22:26 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 101974385 101974384
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.0)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   VCL_return     restart
-   Timestamp      Process: 1545038546.336929 8.103637 0.000027
-   Timestamp      Restart: 1545038546.336932 8.103640 0.000003
-   Link           req 101974386 restart
-   End
```

It then keeps restarting, fetching the 503 error from cache, restarting etc until the restart limit is hit.

Is this behaviour intentional? Does anyone have an idea why this is happening and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the expected behaviour. From the docs:

> A vcl_synth defined object is never stored in cache, contrary to a vcl_backend_error defined object, which may end up in cache. vcl_synth and vcl_backend_error replace vcl_error from Varnish 3.

As usual, you can avoid that simply doing `set beresp.uncacheable = true;` during `vcl_backend_error`.

Comment: Thanks, missed that note.